# Is there a way to host binaries on Azure DevOps kind of like GitHub allows?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment

I develop mostly desktop apps and class libraries, and I am struggling to find an way to host them using pipeline automation.

I know I can push them to a UNC, but then people need to know that path to find them. It works, but is not very user friendly.

What I would like is a way to host them on DevOps Server, like GitHub. On GitHub there is a Release section that you can go to and download the binaries of a project. I know Azure DevOps is geared toward webapps, but has anyone found a way to use build/release pipelines to automate the hosting of binary files?

Comment: *I know Azure DevOps is geared toward webapps* That is a misconception.

Comment: Create a universal artifacts feed. Push binaries to the artifacts feed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the Atifacts which is under the Test Plans in your project in Azure DevOps.

You can publish and download your binaries very easily here. Create a Feed and connect to it with any kinds of packages, including built in ones like NuGet and Maven, or you can customize it which called Universal packages in it.

You may find more useful information at [Azure Artifacts documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/?view=azure-devops), learn [what is Azure Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/overview?view=azure-devops) and how you can [publish and download you binaries via the CLI tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/quickstarts/universal-packages?view=azure-devops&tabs=azuredevops).

Comment: According to those docs I have to use the Azure CLI to publish and download Universal packages. I want to publish them from the pipeline.

Comment: I found the Universal Package task. But when I run it I get the error: ##[error]Failed to get artifact tool. Universal Packages are not supported in Azure DevOps Server. I get this feature is not supported with the on prem DevOps Server.

Comment: You can use the powershell task in pipeline to cll Azure CLI too. As for the error you mentioned, i suggest you can open a new thread and provide more of your error log messages with more related information since information is limit in a comment and one question for one thread is a better way to help someone online looking for similar situation.If you already get how to host your binaries in Azure DevOps, you can accept my post as the answer.